# Unity spawning lots of objects at runtime running slow

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've created a simple project where approx. 7000 cubes are created in the scene (with VR camera) but the problem is that when I move camera to see all cubes the FPS becomes very bad, something like 5-6 frames. My PC is i7 with GTX 1070, and I thought that it have to draw hundred thousands of cubes without any problems. Really, I saw minecraft, it looks like there no problems to draw cubes ))

So question is is it possible to optimize the scene so that all cubes are painted it one call or something to provide a good performance?

I'm actually made all cubes static and there are no textures only standard material...

Here is how it looks now:
[image]

I'm using default Directional Light and It would be good to not change the standard shader because of it great work with light.

Here is how I'm generating the cubes:

```cs
private void AddCube(Vector3 coords)
{
    var particle = (Transform)MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(prototype.transform, holder.transform);

    SetScale(particle);
    SetPosition(particle, coords);

    cubes.Add(particle.gameObject);
    particle.gameObject.isStatic = true;

}

private void SetScale(Transform particle)
{
    particle.localScale = new Vector3(Scale, Scale, Scale);
}

private void SetPosition(Transform particle, Vector3 coords)
{
    particle.position = coords;
}
```

This is the screenshot of Stats:
[image: Stats screenshot]
I have here 41 fps because I moved camera away from cubes to have clean background for the stats panel. Actually after I'm making the cubes 'static' the FPS is depends on are the cubes visible on the screen or not.

Comment: What kind of lighting you have? Do you sue real time GI? Also standard shader is quite expensive, so as first step of optimization I would suggest changing it to obsolete Diffuse.

Comment: Minecraft doesn't have as many object as cube there is. They merge cube to do only one mesh. So a mesh of (for example) 256 cubes. That exactly what you can do, but since you said cube can move, you need to regenerate all of them for each move, so that not the solution.

Comment: Please show us your code with cube generation. Also, in Game view press Stats in top right corner and show screen grab of stats windows. Im suspecting rendering draw calls will be extremely high

Comment: @JerrySwitalski It would be great if I make some performance improvements without changing the standard shader.

Comment: @Alaanor I moved the camera, not the cubes, so it is acceptable if I somehow group all cubes. Does minecraft takes all the cubes in one mesh or some groups of cubes? Is there easy way how to create one mesh from the several gameObjects? does the code proposed by Greg Lukosek does what you meant? StaticBatchingUtility.Combine(GameObject cubesRoot);

Comment: @GregLukosek I checked the profiler and yes, drawing is what takes all the time.

Comment: In addition to @GregLukosek's suggestion, have a look at instancing. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by number of individual objects you are instantiating. If cubes doesnt change their transform after generating you should be able to use StaticBatchingUtility to combine them into one batch.

Call this after generating cubes.

```
StaticBatchingUtility.Combine(GameObject cubesRoot);
```

Comment: looks like it works, but... now after some adjustments I have FPS ~35 when all cubes are visible on the screen, and ~55 if I add the code you mentioned StaticBatchingUtility.Combine(GameObject cubesRoot); So is it maximum what I can get?

Comment: This was your main reason i guess. Change shader to something lighter. Also please tick this as a correct answer